# Edit object from table cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view which displays all the objects and the objects can be deleted, now I need to get it so that I can edit the object from the NSMutableArray and save and relode the table data.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    AssignmentInfo *ai = [self.alist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UILabel *classname = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *assignementText = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    UILabel *date = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];

    classname.text = ai.className;
    assignementText.text = ai.assignmentTitle;
    date.text = ai.dateTimeString;
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Here is a link to the whole project if needed:

http://www.abdelelrafa.com/AssignmentAppTwo.zip

Comment: how you want edit this objects?

Comment: By tapping on the cell to display the vc with the data populated.

Comment: so you want tap a cell and go to another vc for  modify all the data then when you come back to the main controller you want to se the table update?

Comment: Yes exactly how it is supposed to work.

Comment: ok give me few second and a write down the solution, you work on iPad or iphone app?

Comment: Iphone and link is in the post to the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First control-drag your cell to the AddEditViewController in the storyboard(Do a modal segue). Next select the segue and name it "edit". After that go to your AddEditViewController.h and create the following properties:

```
@property (nonatomic)BOOL edit;
@property (nonatomic,strong)AssignmentInfo *assignmentEditing;
```

After that in your AssignmentListViewController.m in your prepareForSegue add:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"edit"]) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = sender;
    AddEditViewController *addEditController = segue.destinationViewController;
    [addEditController setOtherdelegate:self];
    addEditController.edit = YES;
    AssignmentInfo *a = [self.alist objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell].row];
    addEditController.assignmentEditing = a;
    [self.alist removeObject:a];
}
```

Last in your AddEditViewController.m in viewDidLoad add:

```
if (self.edit) {
        self.className.text = self.assignmentEditing.className;
        self.assignmentTitle.text = self.assignmentEditing.assignmentTitle;
        self.assignmentDescription.text = self.assignmentEditing.assignmentDescription;
        NSString *string = self.assignmentEditing.dateTimeString;
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
        NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
        dateTimePicker.date = date;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but when I hit done it doesn't save the values?

Comment: @skoltyno Just edited my post

Comment: @skoltyno If it still does not work please tell...

Comment: sorry but it keeps crashing, and still won't update. I uploaded it again: http://www.abdelelrafa.com/AssignmentAppTwo.zip

Comment: @skoltyno Its not crashing for me... it must be a problem with your data file. Delete the app from the simulator and try again.

Comment: already deleted it and still the same problem, when I try to edit it opens the vc and then allows me to make changes but, they don't display on the table and when I try to edit again it crashes.

Comment: @skoltyno What changes are you making? Name,description,time,class?

Comment: All to test it. and then it crashes.

Comment: @skoltyno Just edited my post...

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want a custom animation, you simple remove the object from your `NSMutableArray` and call the `reloadData` method of your `UITableView` object.

Comment: How does this relate to editing?

Comment: Do you want to give the option to remove items to the users?

Comment: @JeroValli yes I want to use the default method.

Comment: Take a look to this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_Q_io5M-3s

Comment: @JeroValli I just watched it, it doesn't show how to edit the object, only how to delete and add, I already have both of those working, I need to be able to edit the object.

Comment: I still dont get why deleting and editing is the same…